# Luajit: compiling bytecode into object format

Tags: linker, lua, luajit

The Luajit manual about the **-b** option says:

> *The output file type is auto-detected from the extension of the output file name:*
>
> - *c — C source file, exported bytecode data.*
> - *h — C header file, static bytecode data.*
> - *obj or o — Object file, exported bytecode data (OS- and architecture-specific).*
> - *raw or any other extension — Raw bytecode file (portable).*

What does it mean to compile it to *object file*? I know it produces a file which then can be linked with other object files generated from C or C++ code.

But how does this work? How would one use the generated object file from other C code? And in which situation would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It embeds the bytecode for a module into a constant array.

If you then export this array from the executable or a shared library, `require` will be able to find it there (and thus not need to search for the `.lua` source file.)